# What is the correct hostname for pgloader when using this tool in docker-in-docker image?

Tags: docker, pgloader

I'm trying to run two databases (msql and postgres) inside a container with docker installed. Unfortunately, when using pgloader, there is an error connecting to the databases. Here are the steps I take:

1. i am pulling dind image: `docker pull docker:dind`
2. running container from dind image: `docker run --privileged --name dind-container --hostname lch -d docker:dind`

- now i enter commands below inside container "dind-container"

3. installing pgloader to container: `apk add --no-cache pgloader`
4. get images of msql db and postgres: `docker pull -q mysql:8` and `docker pull -q postgres:16`
5. create network: docker network create my-network || true
6. run mysql container:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 -d --network my-network --name mysql-db --hostname mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db -e MYSQL_USER=my_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password mysql:8 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

7. run postgres database:

```
docker run -d --network my-network --name postgres-db --hostname postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=my_db -e POSTGRES_USER=my_user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password postgres:16
```

- at this moment it looks like this inside container:

[image: inside docker]

8. waiting for setting up databases
9. run pgloader command:

```
pgloader --with "batch concurrency = 1" mysql://my_user:my_password@lch/my_db postgresql://my_user:my_password@$lch/my_db
```

My question is here: what to enter for 'lch'. I have tried various things, including 'localhost', but there is always an error. I tried logging ip like this and pasting as host: `ip route|awk '{print $3; exit}'`.

Error:

[image: error]

I will add that I managed to do this locally on my machine, then I simply used 'localhost'. However, now I have to use dind image and do it inside container and this is the problem.
I also know that databases are not populated with tables, but that is not a problem here.

Comment: Containers are like separate machines, you refer to them by their IP address or by their name.

Comment: Given the command lines you show here, the hostname of the postgres container is `postgres-db`, and for the mysql container it is `mysql-db` -- but *only* if you are running `pgloader` in a container also connected to `my-network`. If you are running `pgloader` on the host, you cannot access the containers by name; you would need to publish ports (with the `-p` option) to the host and then access them on `localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the database with a correct `docker run -p` option to publish its ports

```bash
docker run -p 5432:5432 ... postgres:16
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then, from a non-container process inside the DinD container, you should be able to access `localhost:5432` to reach the database.  As with other `-p` options, your non-container tool needs to connect to the first `-p` port, and the second `-p` port must match the standard port the process inside the container is using.

If you want to access this port further from the actual host system, you also need to start the DinD container with a similar `-p` option.

Comment: (You're doing several things in this setup I wouldn't generally encourage.  I might avoid the DinD setup, and run these containers "normally" on your host system.  Similarly, I wouldn't try to install extra software in a running container, since that will be lost as soon as the container exits, and more generally I'd recommend avoiding `docker exec` when possible.  It may make sense to run the loader as a container itself, injecting data into it, at which point the normal rules for inter-container communication will apply.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your help, I managed to figure it out. Additionally, I had some omissions and typo in commands above. As @David Maze wrote, port was missing in this  command `docker run -d --network my-network --name postgres-db --hostname postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=my_db -e POSTGRES_USER=my_user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password postgres:16`, and I have '$' unnecessarily here: `...@$lch/my_db`.

Below I put two working solutions:

1. with ports, without network, with pgloader downloaded,
2. without ports, with network, with downloaded container inside which pgloader is installed.

**Solution 1**:

```
docker pull docker:dind 
docker run --privileged --name dind-container --hostname lch -d docker:dind
```

inside "dind-container"

```
apk add --no-cache pgloader  
docker pull -q mysql:8 
docker pull -q postgres:16  
docker run -p 3306:3306 -d --name mysql-db --hostname mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db -e MYSQL_USER=my_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password mysql:8 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres-db --hostname postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=my_db -e POSTGRES_USER=my_user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password postgres:16 
pgloader --with "batch concurrency = 1" mysql://my_user:my_password@localhost/my_db postgresql://my_user:my_password@localhost/my_db
```

or

```
pgloader --with "batch concurrency = 1" mysql://my_user:my_password@lch/my_db postgresql://my_user:my_password@lch/my_db
```

^ both commands work

**Solution 2**:

```
docker pull docker:dind  
docker run --privileged --name dind-container --hostname lch -d docker:dind
```

inside "dind-container"

```
apk add --no-cache pgloader 
docker pull -q mysql:8 
docker pull -q postgres:16  
docker pull dimitri/pgloader  
docker network create my-network || true  
docker run -d --network my-network --name mysql-db --hostname mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db -e MYSQL_USER=my_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password mysql:8 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password  
docker run -d --network my-network --name postgres-db --hostname postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=my_db -e POSTGRES_USER=my_user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password postgres:16  
docker run --network my-network dimitri/pgloader pgloader --with "batch concurrency = 1" mysql://my_user:my_password@mysql/my_db postgresql://my_user:my_password@postgres/my_db
```